# How to connect remotely to airserv-ng server?

Tags: wifi, airmon-ng, airodump-ng

I found a new utils called `airserv-ng` a have tested him and I have a problem :
I want to use `airserv-ng` on one computer and `airodump-ng` on another.
I test that but the problem is when I want to run `airserv-ng` it is an error that told me to run it in monitor mode. 
But when I run it in monitor mode I can't access to this by using ip address (tcp).

Here is the command I tipe on the first computer:

```
sudo airserv-ng -d wlan0
:(error)(run 'airmon-ng start wlan0')
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
sudo airserv-ng -d mon0
```

on the second computer :

```
sudo airplay-ng -9 (ip):666
(666) it's the default port
```

the problem is the (ip) because in the first computer the wireless card was set in monitor mode so it haven;t a ip address specified. 
There someone can help me to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

Your airserv-ng machine will need one connection in monitor mode and a second adapter (Ethernet, Bluetooth, or wireless, doesn't matter) for connecting to a network.